# UISwitch force drag to change setting

Tags: iphone, uiswitch

Is there a way to stop a `UISwitch` from toggling state when you tap on the inactive side? I would like a control that forces a deliberate 'swipe' action to prevent the user accidentally clicking it. I've had a look around but haven't found any setting that removes the instant toggle on tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UISwitch is a child of UIResponder. So you can try to use methods like `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` to detect user actions.

The idea is to set some flag to 'changes are not allowed' state, when user began touches. Change it, depending on touch coordinates - for example, change state to 'changes are allowed', if user moved touch more than 25 pixels right. And make real changes when touches ended, depending on final flag's state.